# Criar select com vários campos

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, firebird, tabela-banco-de-dados

Como criar um select que faça a relação de pelo menos 03 tabelas e apresente um campo de cada tabela pelo menos ?

Comment: Você tem alguma dúvida ou você quer aprender `select`? Recomendo procurar um tutorial, existem vários em português hoje em dia: http://bfy.tw/6Mr4

Comment: Comeca procurando por join, acredito que te ajude.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em um banco de dados relacional armazenamos os dados em tabelas. Essas tabelas se relacionam através de **chaves estrangeiras (FK - *Foreign Key*)**.

Normalmente a **chave primária** de uma tabela estará presente em outra, a qual se relaciona, na forma de **chave estrangeira**.

Um exemplo:
Temos 3 tabelas: **compra**, **produto** e **categoria**.

- **compra** tem um **produto** (está relacionada com produto pelo campo `produto_id`, que é **chave primária (PK - *Primary Key*)** de produto e **chave estrangeira** na tabela compra);
- **produto** tem uma **categoria** (está relacionada com categoria pelo campo *categoria_id*, que é **chave primária** de categoria e **chave estrangeira** na tabela produto);

Para fazer uma consulta que relacione estas 3 tabelas temos que usar **JOIN**.

> Aqui você encontra documentação do MySQL para o assunto, mas o
>   conceito é genérico e aplica-se a praticamente todos os bancos de
>   dados (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Uma `SELECT` pra ilustrar:

```
SELECT c.data, c.valor, p.nome, ct.descricao
  FROM tb_compra c
 INNER JOIN tb_produto p ON p.id = c.produto_id
 INNER JOIN tb_categoria ct ON ct.id = p.categoria_id
 WHERE ct.id = 12;
```

A consulta traz os campos `data` e `valor` da tabela **compra**, o campo `nome` da tabela **produto** e `descrição` da tabela **categoria**.

Espero ter ajudado.